# Hill cipher key space

Tags: keys, prime-numbers, classical-cipher, hill-cipher

Key space is the set of all possible keys that can be used to generate a key. We using the number of valid key to describe it.

I've given a hill cipher of block size $k$ over alphabet of size $p$, where $p$ is prime, how many keys there (valid key)?

Since the hill cipher key is a $k$ x $k$ matrix, all the elements getting from size $p$ alphabets, and from my understanding the number of possible keys should be $p^{k^2}$? but the answer is:

$(p^k-p^0)\times(p^k-p^1)\times(p^k-p^2)\times\cdots\times(p^k-p^{k-1})$

I believe it related to a matrix have a inverse or not, but don't know how to determine.

**EDIT**

By reading from the [Key size of hill cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher#Key_size) from Wiki, got to known something, the example there shown the case cannot inverses is the co-factor of $26$, which is $13$ and $2$.the number of invertible for $n$ blocks over $26$ alphabets are:

$26^{n^{1}}(1-1/2)(1-1/2^{2})\cdots(1-1/2^{n})(1-1/13)(1-1/13^{2})\cdots(1-1/13^{n})$

so apply it to here, because $p$ is prime, so only $1$ or $p$ itself can divide $p^{k^2}$

the result should be:

$p^{k^2}(1-p^{-1})(1-p^{-2})\cdots(1-p^{-k})$

but still different from the answer.

Comment: Actually, they're the same: $p^{k^2}(1-p^{-1})\cdots(1-p^{-k}) = p^{k^2}\prod_{i=1}^k(1-p^{-i}) = \prod_{i=1}^k p^k(1-p^{-i}) = \prod_{i=1}^k (p^k - p^{k-i})$ (this common value is indeed the number of invertible $k\times k$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: @Mehdi Tibouchi ya...i just not see each part got a p^k...so totally it p^(k^2)