# what is number of invertible matrix m*m on$ z_n$?

Tags: hill-cipher

‎

> ‎‎please help me what is number of invertible matrix $‎m*m$‎‎‎ on Group $\mathbb{z}_n$ ?‎‎‎, assuming we know‎ this number in $\mathbb{Z}_p \quad$ (‎p is prime‎‎) is   $‎(p^{n}-1)(p^{n}-p) \cdots (p^n-p^{n-1})‎‎‎‎$

Comment: How is this related to cryptography? $\;$

Comment: You are talking about the [General Linear Group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_linear_group#Over_finite_fields) of matrices of degree m over $\mathbb Z_p$.

Comment: @Ricky Demer: the OP gives a hint with the tag _hill-cipher_, which indeed uses as key an invertible $m\times m$ matrix with elements in $\mathbb Z_n$.

Comment: The question is in fact a duplicate of [this one](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/15493/555), which has a satisfactory solution (if not answer in the sense of the CSE website logic) in comment, and as an edit of the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume you know the number of invertible $m \times m$ matrices over $\mathbb{Z}_{p^k}$ for $p$ prime. Call this number $N(p^k)$.

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, $N(\prod_{i=1}^l p_i^{k_i}) = \prod_{i=1}^l N(p_i^{k_i})$ because a matrix is invertible iff every component in its CRT decomposition is invertible. For $m = 1$, $N$ is just the $\phi$ function.

Finding $N(p^k)$ is another matter.